# Algebraic expansion of $(1+x)^{1/x}$ is?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits

i have to solve 
$ \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{{(1+x})^{1/x}-e+ex/2}{x^2}$ and in the hint it is advised to use the algebraic expansion of $(1+x)^{1/x}$.

Also i know that the algebraic expansion of $(1+x)^{m} = 1+mx+m(m-1){x^2}/2+...$ but this is in the case where m is an integer.
So please help me here with the limit.

Comment: You may assume without loss of generallity that $1/x$ is an integer

Comment: i did try that but the answer do not match. the answer is (11/24).e

Comment: m need not be integer, it must just be a rational number

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Note that you can develop
$$
\begin{gathered}
  \left( {1 + x} \right)^{\,1/x}  = \exp \left( {\frac{1}
{x}\ln \left( {1 + x} \right)} \right) = \exp \left( {1 - \frac{x}
{2} + \frac{{x^{\,2} }}
{3} + O\left( {x^{\,3} } \right)} \right) =  \hfill \\
   = \exp \left( 1 \right)\exp \left( { - \frac{x}
{2}} \right)\exp \left( {\frac{{x^{\,2} }}
{3}} \right)\exp \left( {O\left( {x^{\,3} } \right)} \right) =  \hfill \\
   = e\left( {1 - \frac{x}
{2} + \frac{{x^{\,2} }}
{8}} \right)\left( {1 + \frac{{x^{\,2} }}
{3}} \right) + O\left( {x^{\,3} } \right) = e\left( {1 - \frac{x}
{2} + \frac{{11\;x^{\,2} }}
{{24}} + O\left( {x^{\,3} } \right)} \right) \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered} 
$$
from which
$$
\begin{gathered}
  \frac{1}
{{x^{\,2} }}\left( {\left( {1 + x} \right)^{\,1/x}  - \left( {1 - x/2} \right)e} \right) =  \hfill \\
   = \frac{1}
{{x^{\,2} }}\left( {e\left( {1 - \frac{x}
{2} + \frac{{11\;x^{\,2} }}
{{24}}} \right) - \left( {1 - x/2} \right)e + O\left( {x^{\,3} } \right)} \right) =  \hfill \\
   = \frac{{11}}
{{24}}e + O\left( x \right) \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered} 
$$

Comment: How did u reach to second step: e(1-x/2+x^2/8).. ?

Comment: @Parul, added intermediate step in the answer

Comment: @GCab, how did the terms in the exponent of $e$ convert in multiplication in the fourth term?

Comment: @SarGe do you refer to the expansion of ,e.g., $exp(-x/2)$ into series expansion ?

Comment: Ok, got it. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

Hint: Use
$$ f(x)=f(0)+f'(0)x+\frac{1}{2}f''(c)x^2 $$
where $c$ is between $0$ and $x$.

Update: Let 
$$ f(x)=（1+x)^{1/x}. $$
and then
$$ f'(x)=-（1+x)^{1/x}\frac{x-\ln(1+x)}{x^2(1+x)}, f''(x)=\frac{(x+1)^{\frac{1}{x}-2}(-(3 x+1) x^2+2 (x+1) x^2 \ln (x+1)+(x+1)^2\ln ^2(x+1))}{x^4}. $$
Clearly
\begin{eqnarray}
f(0)&=&\lim_{x\to0}（1+x)^{1/x}=e,f'(0)=\lim_{x\to0}f'(x)=-\frac{e}{2},f''(0)=\frac{11e}{12}.
\end{eqnarray}
So
$$ \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{{(1+x})^{1/x}-e+ex/2}{x^2}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\frac{1}{2}f''(c)x^2}{x^2}=\frac{1}{2}f''(0)=\frac{11e}{24}.$$

Comment: isn't it suppose to be f prime in the second term, also how is it useful here?

Comment: @Parul, yes, you are right.

Comment: You implicitly assume that the function and its derivatives are continuous at $0$. The given function has a removable discontinuity at $0$ and even after removing it, it's difficult to prove that the derivatives are continuous at $0$.

Answer (score 2):

As Zelos points out, you may compute the limit as $x$ approaches 0 by considering the value of your expression at $x=1/m$ for $m$ any nonzero integer. Then $1/x$ is an integer, and your formula applies.

Alternatively your formula, the binomial theorem, applies even when $1/x$ is not an integer, with the proviso that the series will not terminate for negative or non-integer exponents.

Hence you may even use your formula

$$(1+x)^{1/x} = 1 + x/x+\dotsb$$

with or without the assumption that $1/x$ is an integer.

In more detail, the [binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem) gives

$$(1+x)^{1/x} = \sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{1}{m!}\frac{1}{x}\cdot\left(\frac{1}{x}-1\right)\cdot\dotsb\cdot\left(\frac{1}{x}-m+1\right)x^m
$$

Let us expand the expression inside the summation to collect the terms of degree 0, 1, and 2 in $x$.

To find the terms of the expanded product, you must choose one term from each binomial factor in the product. The degree of the term will be determined by how many times you choose the $1/x$ term.

The only way to get a degree 0 term is to choose the $1/x$ from each of the $m$ binomial factors in parentheses, so you get $\frac{1}{m!}\frac{x^m}{x^m}=\frac{1}{m!}$.

If you choose the second term in the binomial factor exactly once, and the $1/x$ $m-1$ times, then you get $m$ linear terms. Those the linear coefficient is the sum of numbers from 0 to $m-1$.

To get a quadratic term, you need to choose the second term exactly twice. The coefficient is thus the sum of all products of two numbers from 0 to $m-1$.

In summary

$$
\frac{1}{m!}\frac{1}{x}\left(\frac{1}{x}-1\right)\cdot\dotsb\cdot\left(\frac{1}{x}-m+1\right)x^m
=
\frac{1}{m!} - \frac{1}{m!}\left(\sum_{j=0}^{m-1} j\right)x +  \frac{1}{m!}\left(\sum_{j=0}^{m-1} \sum_{k=j+1}^{m-1} jk\right)x^2 +o(x^3)$$

Using the [Faulhaber identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula) to evaluate those summations, we get

$$
\frac{1}{m!} - \frac{1}{m!}\left(\frac{m(m-1)}{2}\right )x +  \frac{1}{m!}\left(\frac{m(m-1)(m-2)(3m-1)}{24}\right )x^2 +o(x^3)
$$

Now summing each term over $m$ we see the constant term is $\sum\frac{1}{m!}=e$, the linear coefficient is $-\frac{1}{2}\sum\frac{1}{(m-2)!}=-e/2$, and the quadratic coefficient is (after some reindexing) $\frac{1}{24}\sum\frac{3m-1}{(m-3)!} = \frac{11e}{24}$, which gives the answer.

Comment: i have landed on  $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{{16-6e+x(3e-6)+2x^2}{6(x^2)}$. what to do next?

Comment: You actually need to consider all the terms of the binomial expansion. Every term contributes a constant, all but one contribute a linear term, and you need all those terms to cancel $e-ex/2$. You need to also collect all the quadratic terms.

Comment: wont that become a very long procedure to solve? are u able to think of any other method of solving this limit?

Comment: Yes it seems lengthy. But you requested to use binomial theorem. Shall we try lhopital instead?

Comment: l'hospitals will  go for like ever and ever. ;(

Comment: Yeah it does seem like lhopital will not succeed. Shall we go back to binomial?

Comment: yeah, i think so

Comment: @Parul ok I did it