# Evaluate: $\lim_{n\to \infty} \bigg[n-{n\over e}\bigg(1+{1\over n}\bigg)^n \bigg] $

Tags: limits

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \bigg[n-{n\over e}\bigg(1+{1\over n}\bigg)^n \bigg] $$

My solution: Can we solve this as $$\lim_{n\to \infty}{\bigg(1+{1\over n}\bigg)^n}=e$$
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} {n\over e}\bigg[e-\bigg(1+{1\over n}\bigg)^n \bigg] =0$$ Can we proceed this way? is there anyother way we can approach? Please help . Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can do that!!! In general, $\lim u_n v_n \neq 0$ even if $\lim v_n =0$. An easy example is $u_n =n$ and $v_n =1/n$. However, you can use Taylor expansion at order 2 of $e^{n \ln \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)}$ to get the limit you're looking for.

Comment: you can't because you're dealing with an indetrminate form ($0\cdot \infty$)

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net is there a typo in your comment?

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3986021/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3358294/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3747770/42969 – all found [with Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Clim_%7Bn%5Cto%20%5Cinfty%7D%20%5Cbigg%5Bn-%7Bn%5Cover%20e%7D%5Cbigg(1%2B%7B1%5Cover%20n%7D%5Cbigg)%5En%20%5Cbigg%5D%24)

Answer (score 1):

You can take advantage of the Taylor series of $(1+ x)^{\frac{1}{x}}$,which you can find [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1974159/algebraic-expansion-of-1x1-x-is)
So $\Big(1+\dfrac{1}{n}\Big)^n \sim e(1-\dfrac{1}{2n})$
This yields  $L = \dfrac12$